# Speeding up a pd.apply() function

Tags: python, pandas

I have some example data

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd

    users = 5
    size = users*6

    df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'userid': np.random.choice(np.arange(0, users), size), 
        'a_time': np.random.normal(loc = 1.5, scale = 0.5, size = size), 
        'b_time': np.random.normal(loc = 1.5, scale = 0.5, size = size), 
        }
    )
    df['focus'] = np.where(df.userid % 2 == 0, 'a', 'b')

    test_dat = df[['userid', 'focus', 'a_time', 'b_time']].sort_values('userid').copy(deep = True).reset_index(drop = True)
```

For each `userid`, I need to determine how many times `a_time > b_time` or vice versa, depending on column `focus`.

I have a custom function

```
def some_func(x):
    if (x.focus == 'a').all():
        a = x.a_time
        b = x.b_time
        x['changes'] = (b > a).sum()
        x['days'] = len(a)
    elif (x.focus == 'b').all():
        a = x.a_time
        b = x.b_time
        x['changes'] = (a > b).sum()
        x['days'] = len(a)
    elif (x.focus == 'both').all():
        x['changes'] = 0
        x['days'] = len(a)
    else: 
        x['changes'] = None
        x['days'] = None
    
    return x

test_dat.groupby(['userid', 'focus']).apply(some_func).reset_index(name = 'n_changes')
```

that works just fine when the number of `userid` is small. However, as the number of unique `userid` increases to >100K, this function is almost unbearably slow.

Is there a way to speed up this fx? My guess is that there might be an alternative to the `if-elif-else` syntax in `some_func()` but I'm not sure what that syntax might be. The number of rows for each `userid` is arbitrarily long.

I'm open to non-pandas options if necessary.

Comment: `some_func` is going to get called a row at a time, right?  So what are the `.all()` calls supposed to do?

Comment: @TimRoberts Hmm. Good point. I thought `some_func()` would be applied to each group rather than each row. The `.all()` are meant to verify that all values for `focus` within a `userid` are identical.

Comment: What's the frequency of `x.focus` values, i.e. `x.focus == 'a'`, `x.focus == 'b'`, `x.focus == 'both'` and everything else? Reordering the tests by descending frequency could speed things up. Really, the best way to figure out where to look for optimization opportunities is to profile the code. Lastly, `pandas` is generally going to perform better here than say Python stdlib because these operations are usually vectorized in pandas.

Comment: Looks good to me

Answer (score 0):

A now-deleted answer from another user helped me get to a reasonably-quick solution. After learning that `GroupBy.apply()` does [operate on dataframes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) and that [this answer suggests that `apply()` isn't very performant (at least compared to `transform()`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37106537/how-to-speed-up-pandas-groupby-apply-function-to-be-comparable-to-rs-data-tab), I thought I'd try dropping `apply()` entirely. I don't think this solution is very pretty but with 277161 userid values in 1.36MM rows, it runs in about 32 seconds:

```
# Simulate some data
users = 277161
size = 1360000

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'userid': np.random.choice(np.arange(0, users), size), 
    'a_time': np.random.normal(loc = 1.5, scale = 0.5, size = size), 
    'b_time': np.random.normal(loc = 1.5, scale = 0.5, size = size), 
    }
)
df['focus'] = np.where(df.userid % 2 == 0, 'a', 'b')

test_dat = df[['userid', 'focus', 'a_time', 'b_time']].sort_values('userid').copy(deep = True).reset_index(drop = True)

# Evalute time
start = datetime.now()

test_dat['aux'] = np.where(
        test_dat.focus == 'a', test_dat.a_time.lt(test_dat.b_time), 
        np.where(test_dat.focus == 'b', test_dat.a_time.gt(test_dat.b_time), None))

test = test_dat.groupby(['userid', 'focus'])['aux'].agg([np.sum, np.size]).reset_index()

# the row above for some reason doesn't handle single boolean values well and just 
# returns the boolean values when the number of rows in a group = 1, 
# so I force those remaining boolean values into ints here
test['sum'] = test['sum'].astype(int)

test = test.rename(columns = {'sum': 'changes', 'size': 'days'})

end = datetime.now()
(end - start).seconds
```

I recognize that this isn't an explicit answer to my question (i.e., "speeding up an `apply()` function") but the reality is that this is a workable, reasonably-quick solution.

Comment: Thanks to user @pauls for some earlier help.

Comment: I think you can improve the solution by removing all `np.where` and using only this: `test_dat['aux'] = test_dat.a_time.lt(test_dat.b_time)`. The reason is that we can go to the final `test` dataframe and obtain the changes for `focus=b` by simple subtraction of `changes` from `days`. (I guess there is no case where `test_dat.a_time.lt == test_dat.b_time`.)

Comment: I mean this: `test.loc[test.focus.eq('b'), 'changes'] = test.loc[test.focus.eq('b'), 'days'] - test.loc[test.focus.eq('b'), 'changes']`.